# Fill in missing values (NAs) with values from another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset, missing-data

How do I subset missing values in one dataframe with values from another?

Let's say I have two datasets:

dataset 1 shows the amount of food that is produced by a country each day.

```
 country         day     tonnes of food
## 1       china  1          6
## 2       china  1          NA
## 3       china  2          2
## 4       china  2          NA
```

dataset2 is the average amount of food by day

```
country         day     average tonnes of food
## 1       china  1          6
## 3       china  2          2
```

How can I fill in the NAs of dataset1 with the averages from dataset2.

I.e. IF `is.na(dataset1$tonnes)` is TRUE then fill in with average for day from `dataset2$averagetonnes`

Comment: Just `merge(df1, df2)[-3]`

Comment: what does the `-3` do?

Comment: Removes the third column from the merge (the old third column in the original data).  Have a look at `merge(df1, df2)`. I think `setNames(merge(df1, df2)[-3], names(df1))` is the closest to what you want.

Comment: would that not simply replace all of the values with the averages, as opposed to only the NAs?

Comment: No.  Why would it do that?  There are no averages being calculated there.

Comment: Unless I am using merge incorrectly, it binds the columns of the dataset rather than fill in the NAs.

I.E.

I am left with 3 columns. `"day","tonnes.x","tonnes.y"` 

Rather than two columns `"day" "tonnes"` `tonnes` having the NAs replaced with values from dataframe2.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly using the `match` function will solve your problem. 
**Data:**

```
df1 <- data.frame(country=c(rep('china1',2),rep('china2',2)),day=c(1,1,2,2),tof = c(6,NA,2,NA),stringsAsFactors = F)
df2 <- data.frame(country=c('china1','china2'),day=c(1,2),atof = c(6,2),stringsAsFactors = F)
df1
  country day tof
#1  china1   1   6
#2  china1   1  NA
#3  china2   2   2
#4  china2   2  NA
```

This line will replace the NAs with the averages of the corresponding country of the second data.frame df2. The `match` function results in a vector of positions of matches and `[which(is.na(df1$tof))]` selects the indices where there is a `NA` in the “tof” column.

```
df1$tof[is.na(df1$tof)] <- df2$atof[match(df1$country,df2$country)][which(is.na(df1$tof))]
df1
  country day tof
#1  china1   1   6
#2  china1   1   6
#3  china2   2   2
#4  china2   2   2
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use join in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, on =c("country", "day")][is.na(tonnes.of.food), 
  tonnes.of.food:= average.tonnes.of.food][, average.tonnes.of.food:=NULL][]
#   country day tonnes.of.food
#1:   china   1              6
#2:   china   1              6
#3:   china   2              2
#4:   china   2              2
```

Comment: Do you know of an answer using base, reshape or plyr? I'm not acquainted with data.table.

Comment: @user3200293  It is already posted in the comments by RichardScriven

Comment: That does not give the desired results. Unless I am using merge incorrectly, instead of filling in the NA's, it simply binds the columns of each dataset together.