# Fill missing values from another dataframe with the same columns

Tags: r

I searched various join questions and none seemed to quite answer this. I have two dataframes which each have an ID column and several information columns.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1:100), color = c(rep("blue", 25), rep("red", 25), 
                  rep(NA, 25)), phase = c(rep("liquid", 50), rep("gas", 50)),
                  rand.col = rnorm(100))

df2 <- data.frame(id = c(51:100), color = rep("green", 50), phase = rep("gas", 50))
```

As you can see, df1 is missing some info that is present in df2, while df2 is only a subset of all the ids, but they both have some similar columns. Is there a way to fill the missing values in df1 based on matching ID's from DF2?

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697032/fill-in-missing-values-nas-with-values-from-another-dataframe-in-r) that recommended using merge, but when I tried it, it dropped all the id's that were not present in both dataframes. Plus it required manually dropping duplicate columns and in my real dataset, there will be a large number of these, making doing so cumbersome. Even ignoring that though,

both the recommended solutions:

```
df1 <- setNames(merge(df1, df2)[-2], names(df1))
```

and

```
df1[is.na(df1$color), "color"] <- df2[match(df1$id, df2$id), "color"][which(is.na(df1$color))]
```

did not work for me, throwing various errors.

An alternate solution I have thought of is using `rbind` then dropping incomplete cases. The problem is that in my real dataset, while there are shared columns, there are also non-shared columns so I would have to create intermediate objects of just the shared columns, `rbind`, then drop incomplete cases, then `join` with the original object to regain the dropped columns. This seems unnecessarily roundabout.

In this example it would look like

```
df2 = rbind(df1[,colnames(df2)], df2)
df2 = df2[complete.cases(df2),]
df2 = merge(df1[,c("id", "rand.col")], df2, by = "id")
```

and, in case there are any fully duplicated rows between the two dataframes, I would need to add

```
df2 = unique(df2)
```

This solution will work, but it is cumbersome and as the number of columns that are being matched on increase, it gets even worse. Is there a better solution?

-edit- fixed a problem in my example data pointed out by Sathish

-edit2- Expanded example data

```
df1 = data.frame(id = c(1:100),  wq2 = rnorm(50), wq3 = rnorm(50), wq4 = rnorm(50), 
wq5 = rnorm(50))

df2 = data.frame(id = c(51:100), wq2 = rnorm(50), wq3 = rnorm(50), wq4 = rnorm(50), 
wq5 = rnorm(50))
```

These dataframe represents the case where there are many columns that have incomplete data and a second dataframe that has all of the missing data. Ideally, we would not need to separately list each each column with `wq1 := i.wq1` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to join only by `id` column, you can remove `phase` in the `on` clause of code below.

Also your data in the question has discrepancies, which are corrected in the data posted in this answer.

```
library('data.table')
setDT(df1)  # make data table by reference
setDT(df2)  # make data table by reference
df1[ i = df2, color := i.color, on = .(id, phase)] # join df1 with df2 by id and phase values, and replace color values of df2 with color values of df1

tail(df1)
#     id color phase   rand.col
# 1:  95 green   gas  1.5868335
# 2:  96 green   gas  0.5584864
# 3:  97 green   gas -1.2765922
# 4:  98 green   gas -0.5732654
# 5:  99 green   gas -1.2246126
# 6: 100 green   gas -0.4734006
```

one-liner:

```
setDT(df1)[df2, color := i.color, on = .(id, phase)]
```

**Data:**

```
set.seed(1L)
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1:100), color = c(rep("blue", 25), rep("red", 25), 
                                           rep(NA, 50)), phase = c(rep("liquid", 50), rep("gas", 50)),
                  rand.col = rnorm(100))

df2 <- data.frame(id = c(51:100), color = rep("green", 50), phase = rep("gas", 50))
```

---

**EDIT: based on new data posted in the question**

**Data:**

```
set.seed(1L)
df1 = data.frame(id = c(1:100),  wq2 = rnorm(50), wq3 = rnorm(50), wq4 = rnorm(50), 
                 wq5 = rnorm(50))
set.seed(2423L)
df2 = data.frame(id = c(51:100), wq2 = rnorm(50), wq3 = rnorm(50), wq4 = rnorm(50), 
                 wq5 = rnorm(50))
```

**Code:**

```
library('data.table')
setDT(df1)[ id == 52, ]
#    id       wq2        wq3        wq4         wq5
# 1: 52 0.1836433 -0.6120264 0.04211587 -0.01855983

setDT(df2)[ id == 52, ]
#    id       wq2       wq3        wq4       wq5
# 1: 52 0.3917297 -1.007601 -0.6820783 0.3153687

df1[df2, `:=` ( wq2 = i.wq2,
                wq3 = i.wq3,
                wq4 = i.wq4,
                wq5 = i.wq5), on = .(id)]

setDT(df1)[ id == 52, ]
#    id       wq2       wq3        wq4       wq5
# 1: 52 0.3917297 -1.007601 -0.6820783 0.3153687
```

Comment: This works perfectly thank you. I haven't worked with the data.table package before so I'll have to spend some time familiarizing myself with it.

Comment: Is there a way to replace multiple columns without listing them individually 1 by 1? In my real dataset, there will be about 15 water quality columns that I want to fill with and I'd rather avoid typing them all out individually. The ideal solution would be to tell it to take all columns from a given dataframe, or to be able to list a group of columns by number maybe.

Comment: Sorry, fixed. I had considered adding it in but decided it wasn't relevant to the question I was asking. It's been removed.