# Fill only missing values in dataframe with values from another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

My question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48792176/fill-missing-values-from-another-dataframe-with-the-same-columns). Let's say I have two dataframes as shown below:

```
set.seed(5)
df1 <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c('2001-01-01', '2001-02-01', '2001-03-01', '2001-04-01', '2001-05-01')),
                  val1=rnorm(5), val2=c(rnorm(3), NA, NA), val3=c(rnorm(3), NA, NA))

df2 <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c('2001-03-01', '2001-04-01', '2001-05-01')),
                  val2=rnorm(3), val3=rnorm(3))
df1
        date        val1       val2       val3
1 2001-01-01 -0.84085548 -0.6029080 -0.2857736
2 2001-02-01  1.38435934 -0.4721664  0.1381082
3 2001-03-01 -1.25549186 -0.6353713  1.2276303
4 2001-04-01  0.07014277         NA         NA
5 2001-05-01  1.71144087         NA         NA

df2
        date       val2       val3
1 2001-03-01 -0.8017795 -1.0717600
2 2001-04-01 -1.0803926 -0.1389861
3 2001-05-01 -0.1575344 -0.5973131
```

`df1` has some missing values in the columns `val2` and `val3`. I want to replace only the missing values in those columns with correct match, match according to `date` from `df2`. From the question that I linked to, here's a potential solution using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
df1[i = df2, val2 := i.val2, on = .(date)]
df1
         date        val1       val2       val3
1: 2001-01-01 -0.84085548 -0.6029080 -0.2857736
2: 2001-02-01  1.38435934 -0.4721664  0.1381082
3: 2001-03-01 -1.25549186 -0.8017795  1.2276303
4: 2001-04-01  0.07014277 -1.0803926         NA
5: 2001-05-01  1.71144087 -0.1575344         NA
```

The problem here is that it has replaced the 3rd value of `val2` in `df1` with the matching value in `df2`, even though the 3rd value in `df1` was not originally missing. Also, how can I fill all missing values in `df1` with their matching values in `df2` instead of doing it one column at a time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution using `dplyr` package:

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
  left_join(., df2, by = 'date') %>%
  mutate(
    val2 = ifelse(is.na(val2.x), val2.y, val2.x),
    val3 = ifelse(is.na(val3.x), val3.y, val3.x)
    ) %>%
  select(date, val1, val2, val3)

df1
        date        val1       val2       val3
1 2001-01-01 -0.84085548 -0.6029080 -0.2857736
2 2001-02-01  1.38435934 -0.4721664  0.1381082
3 2001-03-01 -1.25549186 -0.6353713  1.2276303
4 2001-04-01  0.07014277 -1.0803926 -0.1389861
5 2001-05-01  1.71144087 -0.1575344 -0.5973131
```

Finally with the seed set. Damn, I kept getting different results! :)

With the `coalesce` option correctly pointed out below:

```
df1 %>%
  left_join(., df2, by = 'date') %>%
  mutate(
    val2 = coalesce(val2.x, val2.y),
    val3 = coalesce(val3.x, val3.y)
    ) %>%
  select(date, val1, val2, val3)
```

Cleaner than `ifelse`, for sure.